# ASP.NET Core MVC model values not matching the model after HttpGet

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is a simple view model:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is a simple HttpGet:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetContactEdit(int? contactId)
    {
        ContactViewModel viewModel = new ContactViewModel();

        if (contactId > 0)
        {
            viewModel = Contact.Get<ContactViewModel>(contactId.Value).Content;
        }

        return PartialView("~/Views/AddressBook/PartialViews/_ContactEdit.cshtml", viewModel);
    }
```

And here is a simple partial view .cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactEditForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ContactId)
    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What happens is no matter what value is assigned to `viewModel.ContactId` in the `GetContactEdit` function, the `.cshtml` will render ONLY what is passed in to the function as `int? contactId`.

For example, if I call

```
/ContactController/GetContactEdit?contactId=-1
```

and then in the controller manually override it right before the end to be `viewModel.ContactId=99`, the rendered HTML will always be `<input type=hidden value=-1 />` - I can even check the `@Model` all the way to the rendering phase and it's 99, BUT once the view is rendered, it's actually -1.

There clearly seems to be some binding / override thing between the controller action and the model names, but I can't figure out what. This is my first ASP.NET Core MVC project and this is not an issue in ASP.NET MVC projects.

What am I missing about how URL binding, etc works here? Why does the `GET` request parameter override my actual model when it comes to rendering?

Comment: A simple workaround would to just rename the field on the `ContactViewModel`

Comment: Yeah, changing the parameter or the viewmodel names work, but I was trying to identify what process / difference makes this happen now. For example, in Framework MVC, this is not an issue. There's some sort of parameter / request mapping that's changed and I was trying to get a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the issue lies in the way the HiddenFor helper is being used in your partial view. The HiddenFor helper generates an input element with a hidden type and binds it to the specified property of the model. However, it takes into account the value provided in the request data, including query parameters, to determine the initial value for the hidden field.

In your case, when you call the GetContactEdit action with a query parameter contactId=-1, it overrides the initial value of viewModel.ContactId you set in the controller action. As a result, the HiddenFor helper generates an input field with the value -1.

To fix this issue, you can modify your code as follows:

Remove the contactId parameter from the GetContactEdit action:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetContactEdit(int? contactId)
{
    ContactViewModel viewModel = new ContactViewModel();

    if (contactId > 0)
    {
        viewModel = Contact.Get<ContactViewModel>(contactId.Value).Content;
        viewModel.ContactId = contactId.Value; // Set the value explicitly
    }

    return PartialView("~/Views/AddressBook/PartialViews/_ContactEdit.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: I did play around with things like that - you're right in that there's some form of "query parameter takes precedence over the model" and I'm trying to find what's the root cause (i.e. this is new in Core over Framework, our old platform). Your added line wouldn't affect it because query/model match in that case - however, if they are different, it ALWAYS renders HiddenFor with the query string, not the model. Was trying to find the root cause.